# Phaser 3 inside webview

Tags: javascript, webview, phaser-framework

Thanks in advance.

I'm a little bit stopped and frustrated with phaser and it's cache system that it seems can't load resources with protocol "file://".

Normally it is not a problem because it runs on a browser online using "http" or "https" protocol, that works perfectly.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

This is my code, usually way to cache resources:

```
preload: function(){
    game.load.image('background', 'white.jpg');
    game.load.image('ball', 'bubble256.png');
    game.load.audio('explode', 'explosion.ogg');
}
```

And the code running inside webview looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw5Fs.jpg

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to use file://?

Comment: nops, but inside webview I need to path the file to cache resources no?

Answer (score 2):

I had a simar issue. In my case, I added 'blob:' to img-src inside meta in index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content: blob:;">
```